# How to fix Monogame WP8 Touch Position bug?

Tags: monogame, touch, windows-phone-8

Normally below code will result in X:Infinity, Y:Infinity

```
TouchCollection touchState = TouchPanel.GetState();

foreach (TouchLocation t in touchState)
{
    if (t.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
    {
        vb.ButtonTouched((int)t.Position.X, (int)t.Position.Y);
    }
}
```

Then, I followed this https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/1046 and added below code at the first line in update method. (I still don't know how it's worked, but it fixed the problem)

```
if (_firstUpdate)
{
    typeof(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.TouchPanel).GetField("_touchScale",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, Vector2.One);
    _firstUpdate = false;
}
```

And then, when I randomly testing something, there are several area that won't read the user touch.

[image: The actual screenshoot]

The tile with the purple dude is the area which won't receive user input (It don't even detect "Pressed", the TouchCollection.Count = 0)

Any idea how to fix this?

UPDATE 1 : The second attempt in recompiling

[image]

The difference is weird. Dunno why the consistent clickable area is just 2/3 area to the left

UPDATE 2 :
After trying to rotate to landscape and back to portrait to randomly testing, then the outcome become :

[image]

Comment: Are you able to test on a real device?  It's possible the emulation is flawed.  (Though you clearly have code problems as well.)

Comment: I'm afraid not. I don't own WP8 yet. My teacher tries the code above in monogame non-WP8 and it worked well. I think the problem is because the ClientBound is invalid. But I doesn't know how to fix it. https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/431035

Comment: Did you solve the issue of certain areas not responding to touch? I am still having this problem.

Comment: I've post an answer to this, just now. EDIT : Ouch sorry I answered wrong problem. I'll fix it

Comment: I've posted the correct one recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 changes I made to solve this :

1) Make some changes in GamePage.xaml.

2) Using the different way to use TouchPanel.

3) Using the monogame-develop source code as my project reference instead of the installed one (3.0.1).

#

1) Make some changes in GamePage.xaml

Normally, when you are first created a monogame project, there are these codes in the GamePage.xaml.

```
<DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid x:Name="XnaSurface" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

    </Grid>
</DrawingSurfaceBackgroundGrid>
```

....Change it into :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <MediaElement />
    <DrawingSurface x:Name="XnaSurface" />
</Grid>
```

2) Using the different way to use TouchPanel.

First step, is to add enabled gestures you want in your game. Set it in your Game1.cs constructor (TouchPanel.EnabledGestures)

```
Game1()
{
    _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag | GestureType.Tap;
}
```

You can add in extra enabled gestures by adding | Gesture.DoubleTap (for example), etc.

Second step is to use below code to detect your touch (put it in your update method)

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    {
        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
        switch (gesture.GestureType)
        {
            case GestureType.Tap:
            {
                //what to do if a tap is detected??
            }break;
            case GestureType.FreeDrag:
            {
                //what to do if a freedrag is detected??
            }break
            //and so on, depends on your enabledgestures..
        }
   }
}
```

3) Using the monogame-develop source code as my project reference instead of the installed one (3.0.1).

There is some bugs in MonoGame 3.0.1, so after I read & asked several times at the monogame forum, it's said that the "developed" monogame source code, is already corrected some problems (including mine). But since they hasn't released the "install" version, I need to use it directly from the source code. This is how :

https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/453170

That's my question thread, and it already answered (and solved) clearly.

#

Hope those helps.